# 3d functions and matrices in Python -- should I use NumPy?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix, dimension

I am new to Python and programming and am trying to understand how arrays with internal relations are usually handled. I tried making a multiplication table using lists in two and three dimensions and got this (for the multiplication table up to 4):

```
n = 4
a = [x for x in range(1,n+1)]
b = [x for x in range(1,n+1)]
mp_table = []
for i in a:
    c = []
    for j in b:
        c.append(i*j)
    mp_table.append(c)
print(mp_table)
```

This outputs [[1, 2, 3, 4], [2, 4, 6, 8], [3, 6, 9, 12], [4, 8, 12, 16]] as expected.

In three dimensions this code works:

```
n = 4
a = [x for x in range(1,n+1)]
b = [x for x in range(1,n+1)]
mp_table = []
for i in a:
    c = []
    for j in b:
        c.append([i*j*t for t in range(1, n+1)])
    mp_table.append(c)
print(mp_table)
```

Output:

```
[[[1, 2, 3, 4], [2, 4, 6, 8], [3, 6, 9, 12], [4, 8, 12, 16]], [[2, 4, 6, 8], [4, 8, 12, 16], [6, 12, 18, 24], [8, 16, 24, 32]], [[3, 6, 9, 12], [6, 12, 18, 24], [9, 18, 27, 36], [12, 24, 36, 48]], [[4, 8, 12, 16], [8, 16, 24, 32], [12, 24, 36, 48], [16, 32, 48, 64]]]
```

However, I have not been able to find a way to do the same thing in NumPy. I am also not sure how to generalize so that the dimensions of the output can be entered instead of having to nest list comprehensions. Is there an easier/better way to generate multidimensional arrays with functions in Python?

Comment: Have you read the beginner's docs at the official numpy website?  https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/absolute_beginners.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using or without using numpy, declaring your arrays a and b is not necessary. For avoiding the nested lists using comprehension, use numpy.zeros

look this solution:

for 2D:

```
import numpy as np
n = 4
mp_table = np.zeros((n, n), dtype=np.uint16)
for i in range(1, n+1):
    for j in range(1, n+1):
        mp_table[i-1][j-1] = i*j
        
print(mp_table)
```

output:

```
[[ 1  2  3  4]
 [ 2  4  6  8]
 [ 3  6  9 12]
 [ 4  8 12 16]]
```

And for 3d would be almost the same, but with one more loop:

```
import numpy as np
n = 4
mp_table = np.zeros((n, n, n), dtype=np.uint16)

for i in range(1, n+1):
    for j in range(1, n+1):
        for k in range(1, n+1):
            mp_table[i-1][j-1][k-1] = i*j*k
print(mp_table)
```

output:

```
[[[ 1  2  3  4]
  [ 2  4  6  8]
  [ 3  6  9 12]
  [ 4  8 12 16]]
  ...

 [[ 4  8 12 16]
  [ 8 16 24 32]
  [12 24 36 48]
  [16 32 48 64]]]
```

EDIT: You may construct each matrix in one single line too, if you want your code to look pretty:

```
[np.linspace(i, n*i, n, dtype=np.uint16) for i in range(1, n+1)] # 2D
[[np.linspace(i*j, n*i*j, n, dtype=np.uint16) for i in range(1, n+1)] for j in range(1, n+1)] # 3D
```